# Infinite Recursion in D3 Quadtree

Tags: javascript, d3.js, coffeescript, quadtree

I am trying to add an element to a quadtree in D3 but I am getting a "RangeError: Maximum stack size exceeded' error in the console whenever I add more than one element. My quadtree declaration looks like this (in CoffeeScript):

```
quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree()
               .x((d) -> x_scale(d[dim_1])) 
               .y(0)

quadroot = quadtree([])

... later in another function (quadtree and quadroot are both scoped globally) ...
quadtree.extent([[x_scale.range()[0], 0],[x_scale.range()[1], 0]])

datapoints = datapoints_g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(vis_data)

datapoints.exit()
    .remove()

# now add / transition datapoints
datapoints.enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", x_scale.domain()[0])
    .attr("cy", y_scale.domain()[0])
    .on("mouseover", showDetails)
    .on("mouseout", hideDetails)

datapoints
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("r", (d) -> 
        if sizeBy == 'none'
            return datapoint_size
        else
            return size_scale(d[sizeBy]))
    .attr("cx", (d) -> x_scale(d[dim_1]))
    .attr("cy", (d) -> 
        if dim_2 != 'none'
            y_scale(d[dim_2])
        else
                quadroot.add(d)
                # calculateOffset(maxR)
            )
```

I am attempting to modify the example from http://fiddle.jshell.net/6cW9u/8/, just FYI; however, I still get the infinite recursion error upon adding the second element to the quadroot even when I comment out all of the other code from the example.

Any guidance would be appreciated greatly!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally, stack overflow errors and quadtrees mean that you're adding an element outside of the quadtree's extent.  Are you sure you're calculating the x_scale domain and range correctly, so that all your x values will be within the range you're using for the extent?

Comment: That ended up being the problem, thanks!

Comment: Great.  Glad you got it figured out.  Marking to close since the actual problem doesn't really match the question -- the quadtree issue was just a symptom.

Comment: @AmeliaBR's comment resolved a similar problem I just encountered, adapting this quadtree label placement code for a radial layout pie chart to a line chart. Thanks!